# Two clicks instead one when use scrollView in react-native

Tags: react-native, keyboard, scrollview

When I use a `<ScrollView>` in react-native and the **keyboard** is open, I need use two clicks instead one to execute a button.
The first click only close the keyboard and the second click execute the action from button. The clicks are executed in the same point of the screen(over the button). I use `<KeyboardAvoidView>` too because.

```
        <KeyboardAvoidingView
            behavior={Platform.OS === 'ios' ? 'padding' : 'height'}
            style={styles.Container}
        >
            <ScrollView>
                <Components/>
                <Components/>
                <Components/>
                <Components/>
                <Components/>
                <Button/>
            </ScrollView>
        </KeyboardAvoidingView>
```

With ScrollView

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eKtAg.gif)

Without ScrollView (Desire behavior)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sGVFt.gif)

I make some tests:

1. When remove `<ScrollView>` :  I use one click but not display the button on screen because I have many componentes;
2. Uses `<keyboardAvoidingView>` not alter the behavior from `<ScrollView>`
3. I try uses <KeyboardAwareScrollView> but I couldn't install it.

   ```
   "react": "18.2.0",
   "react-native": "0.71.2",
   ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you're looking for the [keyboardShouldPersistTaps](https://reactnative.dev/docs/scrollview#keyboardshouldpersisttaps) prop.

Comment: Perfect!!! In my case, I did use 'never' and everything ok. Thanks a lot.